# jquery data table, count several rows as a single row for the dropdown to select number of entries to show

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using jquery [data table](http://www.datatables.net/) ,  with the following code I get the dropdown option values  just above the table to be 70,175,350 and All. I want the values to show up as 10, 25, 50, All, but every single row count should actually be equal to 7 rows.So When I select 10 from the drodown, the table should show 10*7=70 rows, for 25 it should show up 175 rows etc.

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

     "sDom": 'T<"clear">lrtip',

            "oTableTools": {


            "bSort": false,

            "sSwfPath": "DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",

            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sFileName": "*.xls"
                }
            ]

        },
        "aaSorting" : [],
         "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [70, 175, 350, "All"]],



     });
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
"aLengthMenu": [[70, 175, 350, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
```

From DataTables web site: http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

> This parameter is either a 1D array of options which will be used for
>   both the displayed option and the value, or a 2D array (shown in this
>   example) which will use the array in the first position as the value,
>   and the array in the second position as the displayed options (useful
>   for language strings such as 'All').

**Edit for iDisplayLength**

The above will initially only show 10 rows.  So use iDisplayLength:70 in the call to .dataTable.  See this jsFiddle, which I believe works how you ask: http://jsfiddle.net/Ptcdv/

The code you will need is something like this:

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
      aaData: data,
    "aLengthMenu": [[70, 175, 350, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 70
     })
```

Without the "iDisplayLength", dataTables initially only shows 10 rows.

Comment: that makes the data table to show as if the code were  `"aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, "All"], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying.  DataTables expects either a 1-dimensional array or a 2-dimensional array.  If given a 1-dimensional array, the numbers provided will be shown in the option dropdown, and used for the values of number of rows to display.  If you give it a 2-dimensional array, the first set of numbers will be used as the number of rows to show, the second set of numbers will be shown in the display.  So if you use the array I gave you, "10" will show in the drop down, but when selected, 70 rows will be displayed.